# Kendo sortable : cannot edit text input inside of the sortable table

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have following sortable table with sortable rows by using:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/sortable/events

```
<tbody class="playlist" kendo-sortable k-placeholder="placeholder" k-hint="hint">
    <!-- IF NOTHING IS FOUND-->
    <tr ng-if="projectDetail.projectOrderViewConfiguration.projectEntries.length == 0">
        <td colspan="9"><h1>{{ 'ADD_SOME_ITEMS_FROM_LEFT_COLUMN' | translate }}</h1></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ELSE WRITEOUT-->
    <tr  ng-repeat="projectEntry in projectDetail.projectOrderViewConfiguration.projectEntries">
        <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="projectEntry.entry.defaultName"  class="form-control" id="cwConnectorTeam" value="{{entry.defaultName}}" />
        </td>
        <td>
        <input type="text" ng-model="projectEntry.projectLabel"  class="form-control" id="cwConnectorTeam" value="{{entry.defaultName}}" />
        </td>
        <td><a ng-click="removeProjectEntryItem('{{projectEntry.id}}')">remove</a></td>
    </tr>
    <!-- ELSE WRITEOUT-->
</tbody>
```

and JS

```
// MAKE SELECTED ENTRIES SORTABLE
$scope.placeholder = function(element) {
    return element.clone().addClass("placeholder").text("drop here");
};
$scope.hint = function(element) {
    return element.clone().addClass("hint");
};
```

Problem is that if I tried to click on input filed I found that is not editable (maybe some z-index layer on high position).

I would like to have sortable and editable rows together. How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you thought about using a Kendo UI Grid? Sorting and editing (plus a lot of other features) are built-in.

Answer (score 10):

Kendo UI's sortable widget now has a way of handling this with an [ignore](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/sortable#configuration-ignore) option:

```
$("#sortable").kendoSortable({ 
    ignore: "input"
});
```