# KendoSortable in Angular doesn't enable input fields

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-sortable

[In this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/ba8TioaM7PQYflPIwgzw?p=preview) I have a UL list decorated with kendo-sortable and another list without the decoration. In the first case, the input fields are disabled (apparently disabled to allow dragging on the fields) while in the second list the input fields are enabled. How to make the fields enabled in the first list?

HTML:

```
<ul kendo-sortable="list">
      <li style="list-style-type:none" ng-repeat="c in conditions">
            {{$index}}
            <input ng-model="c.fieldA" style="width:60px" class="k-textbox"/> 
            <select kendo-drop-down-list style="width:60px" ng-model="c.oper">
              <option value="0">=</option>
              <option value="1">&gt;</option>
              <option value="2">&lt;</option>
            </select> 
            <input ng-model="c.fieldB" style="width:60px" class="k-textbox" /> 
      </li>
  </ul>

  Same list without sortable (fields enabled):
  <ul>
      <li style="list-style-type:none" ng-repeat="c in conditions">
            {{$index}}
            <input ng-model="c.fieldA" style="width:60px" class="k-textbox" /> 
            <select kendo-drop-down-list style="width:60px" ng-model="c.oper">
              <option value="0">=</option>
              <option value="1">&gt;</option>
              <option value="2">&lt;</option>
            </select> 
            <input ng-model="c.fieldB" style="width:60px" class="k-textbox" /> 
      </li>
  </ul>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("app", [ "kendo.directives" ]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

   $scope.conditions = [];

   var load = function() {

          var c = {
                  fieldA: '111',
                  oper: 0,
                  fieldB: '222'
            };

            $scope.conditions.push(c);


            var c1 = {
                  fieldA: '333',
                  oper: 0,
                  fieldB: '444'
            };

            $scope.conditions.push(c1);
   };


    $scope.$on("kendoWidgetCreated", function(event, widget){
          if (widget === $scope.list) {
              load();
          }
      });

}
```

Comment: It seems like this is an [old](http://www.telerik.com/forums/sortable-including-inputs-issue) [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27405996/kendo-sortable-cannot-edit-text-input-inside-of-the-sortable-table). Have you tried those solutions (especially using `ignore` option)?

Comment: yes, I thought about using a grid with editable cells, however I'd like to know first if there's a simpler solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide an [ignore](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/sortable#configuration-ignore) option:

```
<ul kendo-sortable="list" k-ignore="'input'">
  <li style="list-style-type:none" ng-repeat="c in conditions">
        {{$index}}
        <input ng-model="c.fieldA" style="width:60px" class="k-textbox" /> 
        <select kendo-drop-down-list style="width:60px" ng-model="c.oper">
          <option value="0">=</option>
          <option value="1">&gt;</option>
          <option value="2">&lt;</option>
        </select> 
        <input ng-model="c.fieldB" style="width:60px" class="k-textbox" /> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

([demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/go2ptqxnf6cNEQ1vmgcB?p=preview))

Comment: Saved my life - I was missing the single quotes inside the double quotes!!